# What is the syntax for a default constructor for a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Is it forbidden in C# to implement a default constructor for a generic class?

If not, why the code below does not compile? (When I remove `<T>` it compiles though)

What is the correct way of defining a default constructor for a generic class then?

```
public class Cell<T> 
{
    public Cell<T>()
    {
    }
}
```

**Compile Time Error**: Error   1   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You don't provide the type parameter in the constructor. This is how you should do it.

```
public class Cell<T> 
{
    public Cell()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: would be nice to extend this answer in case there is a Cell base class as well where `Cell<T>: Cell`

Answer (score 13):

And if you need the Type as a property:

```
public class Cell<T>
{
    public Cell()
    {
        TheType = typeof(T);
    }

    public Type TheType { get;}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

And if you need to inject an instance of the type:

```
public class Cell<T>
{
    public T Thing { get; }

    public Cell(T thing)
    {
        Thing = thing;
    }
}
```