# is a 'field' but is used like a type - C#

Tags: c#

I have to create an implementation of a stack.

I want to create a class that I can use like so:

```
Stack<string> myStack = new Stack<string>();

myStack.Push("Harold");
myStack.Push("Evie");

myStack.Pop(); // => "Evie"
```

Here's what I've written so far:

```
public class Stack<T> {
    private T[] stack;
    private int stackPointer;

    public Stack<T>() {
        this.stackPointer = -1;
    }
}
```

But already I am getting this error from VS:

```
this.stackPointer = -1;
// ERROR: stackPointer is a field but is used like a type.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? (Note I am extremely new to C#)

Comment: your ctor doesn't need the type argument

Comment: Not an answer, but [it exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701106/what-is-the-syntax-for-a-default-constructor-for-a-generic-class but if you want to use it like a real `Stack` you need to inherit from it: `public class Stack<T>: System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>{}`

Comment: I think the duplicate won´t match, the error here is clearly not because of a member-call in the class-body. Anyway the error can have plenty of reasons, the probability of finding a duplicate for this specific one is quite little, I guess. We can however close this question as simply typo.

Comment: The important thing is you got more than one error, and the one you asked about was because you hadn't sorted the first one(s)

Comment: As a side note, someone with your reputation score surely would have googled the error message before posting and been able to find _What does this mean_, right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess we can make this a duplicate of the question you´ve linked to.

Comment: FYI If you want to implement a stack your underlying data type should probably be a linked list instead of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the type in the constructor, like this:

```
public class Stack<T> {
    private T[] stack;
    private int stackPointer;

    public Stack() {
        this.stackPointer = -1;
    }
}
```

Take a look at this Microsoft [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx) about generics which actually includes an implementation of a generic stack class.

[image]

Comment: It migh be worth explaining why the stated error happens as well as the  `unexpected (` when the consturctor signature is wrong, making this not a 100% duplicate